# How do I register additional ConfigurationSourceProviders in Dropwizard?

Tags: dropwizard

I have created a new `ConfigurationSourceProvider`, but cannot find how to register it in Dropwizard.
Also, this provider contains arbitrary key-value pairs, how does that fit in with the "one-getter-per-key" strategy that the DW configuration mechanism seems to favour? I would need to make calls like this:

```java
String value = cfg.getValue("some-key")
```

Answer (score 0):

From version 0.7, you can set the `ConfigurationSourceProvider` on the `BootStrap` class. For example, override the `initialize` method in your [`Application`](http://dropwizard.io/manual/core.html#application) class like so:

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<RestApplicationConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(new UrlConfigurationSourceProvider());
}
```